# Spring Boot 1.4 vs 1.5 and Spring Data Rest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have this entity:

```
    Type
        ...
        @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="type")
        private List<Property> properties;

        public void setProperties(List<Property> properties) {
        ...
        }
    ...
```

And a SDR-Repo which handles the CRUD opreations for Type.
Property has no own repo.

When I use SB 1.4.1 setProperties is called for POST, PUT and PATCH requests.
When I upgrade to SB 1.5.4 setProperties is no longer called for PATCH requests.

Was it it a bug in 1.4.1 or is it a new bug in 1.5.4?

Thank you

Comment: No one an idea?